# Junit preview window not showing in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, junit

I'm trying to run a simple JUnit test in Eclipse, but the preview pane with the very noticeable green/red bar will not show, instead it only shows the normal console window.

I checked that I run JUnit 4 in the run configuration.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestF {

  @Test
  public void test() {
    AClass a = new AClass();
    int t = a.Double(2);
    assertEquals(4, t);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `Window->Show view` check there for `JUnit`. If it is not there then expand `Window->Show view->Other` and find there `JUnit`

Comment: Tried and nothing happened. The preview still won't show

Comment: Then you probably have it minimalized on somewhere. Look around for smal green red JU icon. Most probably on the far right of eclipse window

Comment: Looked everywhere couldn't find it. If I switch to Java EE perspective it works. Odd.

Comment: You can try to customize perspective (Window->Customize perspective) and check fo JUnit entries there. Hard to tell why your GUI is not displaying something not even seen the screenshot ;)

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Window -> Perspective -> Reset Perspective...`
Then `Window -> Show View -> Other ->` search for `JUnit` and select it.

Answer (score 0):

Open up Java EE, then Window->Show View --> JUnit...then switch back to Jave perspective and Window->Show View --> JUnit. you should now see the Junit window.